# Change space between bars in histogram - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a histogram in RStudio with the following code:

```
ggplot(data_csv, aes(x=Phasenew, fill=Success)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, position = "dodge", color="white")
```

What I want to do now, is to add more space between the bars of the histgram. I already tried the "width" parameter, but that one obviously does not work in histogram. Also I tried to make the outline bigger in white, but this will not show the correct length of the bar. Does anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: histograms do not have gaps.  perhaps you want a bar chart instead?

Comment: I have never heard of histograms with width!!

Answer (score 1):

As two people wrote already in the comments, I also feel that your attempt to change the space between the 'bar' of a histogram is based on a misunderstanding about the nature of a histogram. Here the frequency of your events is represented as areas of the cells in the histogram. Or to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram):

> the range of values—that is, divide the entire range of values into a series of intervals—and then count how many values fall into each interval

A priori these cells do not even need to have the same width (in the case your class widths would differ).

Perhaps what you are looking for is `geom_bar` (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)

```r
ggplot(data_csv, aes(x=Phasenew, fill=Success)) +
  geom_bar()
```